# publication ethics

Tags: experimental-physics, x-rays

What does it mean if somebody publishes the same concept of my paper with some changes without citing it although the paper has been published 5 years before his, and the concept was clearly first introduced in my paper? It is quite frustrating to know that nobody cares about your research, especially if you are a young researcher. How to cope with this disappointing feeling?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physics but ethics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics; perhaps [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com) is a better fit.

Comment: Don't universities have ethics boards of some kind or another? Do physicists have a professional code of conduct?

Comment: One answer is to write a letter to the journal that published the other worked pointing out your earlier work.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to just "cope with the disappointing feeling", you are setting yourself up for the same thing to happen again and again. You need to stand up for your rights, if the situation allows this.

But it's unclear from your question, whether this was a case of deliberate plagiarism, or just parallel invention.

Comment: It would be fine if the other paper just cited my work. It never mentioned anything although my work has been published 5 years before the new paper. The new paper wrote about exactly the same principle, the same purpose and conclusion, but a different parameter range, that is much less exciting than mine, by field common sense. The new paper looks fancy, and attractive and is published in a well-known journal and my paper was published in a less ranked journal when I was a MSc student.